# Google Places API Autocomplete works only for one input field

Tags: javascript, google-places-api

So I want to add the Places Autocomplete feature for 2 input fields in my app, on for departure and the other for arrivals. But for somereason when I try to add both, it doesn't seem to work.

```
// GOOGLE MAPS API
function initMap(){
    let passengerDeparture = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
        document.getElementById('id_departure'),
        {
            types:['address'],
            componentRestrictions:{'country':["lk"]},
            fields:['place_id', 'name', 'geometry']
        }
    )
    passengerDeparture.addListener('place_changed', onPlaceChanged(passengerDeparture))

    let passengerArrival = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
        document.getElementById('id_arrival'),
        {
            types:['address'],
            componentRestrictions:{'country':["lk"]},
            fields:['place_id', 'name', 'geometry']
        }
    )
    passengerArrival.addListener('place_changed', onPlaceChanged(passengerArrival))
}

function onPlaceChanged(autoCompleteObj){
    let place = autoCompleteObj.getPlace()
    if (!place.geometry){
        alert("Please choose a valid item")
        document.getElementById('id_departure').value = ""
    }else{
        alert(place.geometry.location.lat())
        alert(place.place_id)
    }
}
```

This is my JS.

The autocomplete works only for the `id_departure` text field and not the other. Is there any specific reason why?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Soooo when I add the Autocomplete for any input field google automatically, adds the placeholder `Enter a location`. However, this applies only to the `id_departure` text field and not for the `id_arrival` text field.

[image]

I get no kind of error but nothing seems to work.

This is my HTML document.

```
Departure<span class="asteriskField">*</span> </label> <div class=""> <input type="text" name="departure" maxlength="200" class="textinput textInput form-control" required id="id_departure"> <small id="hint_id_departure" class="form-text text-muted">The location from where you are going to leave</small> </div> </div> <div id="div_id_arrival" class="form-group"> <label for="id_arrival" class=" requiredField">
Arrival<span class="asteriskField">*</span> </label> <div class=""> <input type="text" name="arrival" maxlength="200" class="textinput textInput form-control" required id="id_arrival"> <small id="hint_id_arrival" class="form-text text-muted">Where you are going towards.</small> </div> </div> <div id="div_id_date" class="form-group"> <label for="id_date" class=" requiredField">
```

Just for your info, if I get rid of the `passengerDeparture` variable then the `passengerArrival` code works perfectly fine, but what I want is for the `passengerDeparture` and the `passengerArrival` to have the autocomplete feature at the same time.

Comment: What does "doesn't seem to work" mean? It means only one listener is called? Both listeners are called but you get some invalid data/JS error? It means your computer catches on fire? It means nothing happens at all? Is there some console error message? Some networking error? Which places have you tried? I see that in the callback you mention only one id to clear the field, maybe that's the problem?

Comment: share more details html and other js code you written?

Comment: Hey I have done the necessary edits, please check and let me know if this helps

Comment: @AbhinavKumar any ideas now??

Comment: @GACy20 would you be able to help now